# Make a JPopupMenu actually popup

Tags: java, actionlistener

I have a `JFrame` which looks like a typical chat box. To connect and disconnect from the server I implemented a `JPopupMenu` and added a `MouseListener` to the main window.
However the popup menu does not appear.

**Various JComponents in the main window:**

`JTextArea` within a `JScrollPane`

`JTextField` to enter the message

`Send` button

`JScrollPane` and an `ArrayList` to display the users

The popup is supposed to appear no matter where you right click. Be it on the `JTextArea` or the field to enter your message.
To which all components do I add listeners and what listener do I add ?

### Code

**Variables:**

```
    private static A_Chat_Client chatClient;
    public static String userName = "Anonymous";

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();
    public static JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(30,30);
    public static JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    public static JTextField message = new JTextField(10);
    public static JButton send = new JButton("Send");

    public static JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
    public static JMenuItem connect = new JMenuItem("Connect");
    public static JMenuItem disconnect = new JMenuItem("Disconnect");
    public static JMenuItem help = new JMenuItem("Help");

    public static JList usersOnline = new JList();
    public static JScrollPane userPane = new JScrollPane(usersOnline);
```

**Main method**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        buildMainWindow();
        initialize();
        addListeners();
        popup.show(mainFrame, 0, 0); //forcefully popup
    }
```

**addListeners()**

```
public static void addListeners(){

        mainFrame.addMouseListener(new MouseHandler());

        send.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                actionSend();
            }
        });
        connect.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                actionConnect();
            }
        });
        disconnect.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                actionDisconnect();
            }
        });
        help.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                actionHelp();
            }
        });
    }
```

**class MouseHandler**

```
private static class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter{
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            if(e.isPopupTrigger()){
                popup.show(mainFrame, e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show some code so we have some idea of where the problem is.

Comment: @Doorknob added the code there, only the concerned part :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could attach an [`AWTEventListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/AWTEventListener.html) to the main event queue using [`Toolkit#addAWTEventListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#addAWTEventListener%28java.awt.event.AWTEventListener,%20long%29)

You would then need to check the type of event your are receiving and check to see if it's popup event.

[image]

```
public class TestGlobalPopup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestGlobalPopup();
    }

    public TestGlobalPopup() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
                    if (event instanceof MouseEvent) {
                        MouseEvent me = (MouseEvent) event;
                        if (me.isPopupTrigger()) {
                            Component component = me.getComponent();
                            JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
                            popup.add(new JLabel("Clicked on " + component.getClass().getName()));
                            popup.show(component, me.getX(), me.getY());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            add(new JLabel("Label: "), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(new JTextField(10), gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridwidth = 2;
            add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(5, 20)), gbc);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for that **but** what is wrong with my code ? :) All the events are properly conveyed when I click on the forcefully popped popup but it doesnt work with right click :)

Comment: @littlechild A popup event may occur on a click, press or release, depending on the platform

Comment: @MadProgrammer so I must, as a rule of thumb, also implement the same functionality in `mousePressed()` for cross platform compatibility?

Comment: @littlechild mousePressed, mouseClicked and mouseReleased