# Mouse Listener Event for different JPanels

Tags: java, swing, events, jlabel, mousemotionlistener

Is is possible to have a global mouse motion listener that has different effects depending on what JPanel is clicked (with only using one mouse motion listener)?

For example: I have a JFrame with two added JPanels and a mouse motion listener added to the JFrame. I want the screen to resize when I click on one JPanel, but I want the JFrame to be dragged around when I click the other. I think this can be done using JLabels using the text of the JLabel to check against, same with a JButton.

EDIT: yes this is definitly not the proper way to do things but just wondering if it is possible, if so, how?

EDIT: Just to make things a bit more clearer, I have one class that extends ActionListener, MouseMotionListener, MouseListener. is it possible to have this one class handle all events of a JFrame that has lots of different JPanels attached to it and do something different based off of which JPanel was pressed? (such as having an ID attached to JPanels that I can compare the event.getSource() with)

Comment: `MouseEvent#getSource`?

Comment: getSource gets the JPanel which called it, it would work for manipulating the JPanel. but to call a different event based on what JPanel was clicked wouldn't work sorry.

Comment: unless it's possible to identify a JPanel I can check the event on

Comment: `Is is possible to have a global mouse motion listener that has different effects depending on what JPanel is clicked` - yes but don't do it. A listener should only have one function. In general, when you have if/else logic in a listener you should be using a separate listener. The is a better design that is easier to maintain.

Comment: The only time you should share listeners is when the code is essentially the same for multiple components. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23375276/attaching-a-single-action-listener-to-all-buttons/23375436#23375436 for an example of this approach. The example uses an ActionListener not a MouseListener, but the concept is the same.

Comment: yea I definitely do think this is the proper approach and I will end up doing that. however working with a professor he accidentally said to do this in an assessment and that got me thinking. is it actually possible? and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, a "global" listener, that does different things for different components, is a bad idea, it places too much logic into a single place, couples the code and becomes a maintenance nightmare.

Having said that, you could use a single `MouseListener` added to each component, for example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JPanel left = new TestPane();
                JPanel right = new TestPane();

                left.setBackground(Color.RED);
                right.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

                left.setName("left");
                right.setName("right");

                MouseListener listener = new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        System.out.println(((JPanel)e.getSource()).getName());
                    }
                };

                left.addMouseListener(listener);
                right.addMouseListener(listener);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(left);
                frame.add(right);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

Then you could simple use `MouseEvent#getSource` to determine which component triggered the event. For simplicity, I've supplied a `name` for each panel and displayed that, I would use some other way to identify the component before making a decision about what to do.

The better solution would be to provide a specific `MouseListener` which did a specific job to the each panel as required, this becomes much easier to manage, isolates responsibility, decouples the code and becomes easier to maintain and manage

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for, I know it's bad but wondering if it can be done. accepted.

Comment: I'm kind of loathed to suggest it, but you might also want to have a look at something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330079/make-a-jpopupmenu-actually-popup/14330224#14330224) which makes use of a `AWTEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but I just tested it and it does work, at least as far as my code tests it. Find which box the mouse is over when it's pressed and do stuff accordingly.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame main = new JFrame("test");
    JPanel first = new JPanel();
    JPanel second = new JPanel();
    first.setSize(400, 500);
    first.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    second.setBackground(Color.RED);
    second.setSize(400,500);
    main.setSize(800, 500);
    main.add(first);
    first.setLocation(0,0);
    second.setLocation(400, 500);
    main.add(second);
    main.pack();
    main.setVisible(true);
    main.setSize(800, 500);
    main.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if(first.getBounds().contains(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY())))
            {
                System.out.println("first box");
            }else if(second.getBounds().contains(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY())))
            {
                System.out.println("Second box");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: does this work if I didn't specify the location? and does it work with Mouse Motion Listener? im using BorderLayouts for it.

Comment: Add `MouseListener`s to the panels, see what happens. Adding the same `MouseListener` to each component would allow you to use `MouseEvent#getSource`, but frankly it would be wiser to use a single listener for each

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 2**

This should be your answer, I noticed on debugging that when I click on empty area on the frame I get a component with the name `"null.contentPane"` so I put it in the condition and it worked!, I hope I helped.

```
public class PanelsListener extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PanelsListener pl = new PanelsListener();
    pl.setSize(700, 700);
    pl.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JPanel fp = new JPanel();

    fp.setName("First");
    fp.setSize(200, 200);
    fp.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red));
    JPanel sp = new JPanel();
    sp.setName("Second");
    sp.setSize(200, 200);
    sp.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.blue));
    pl.add(fp);
    pl.add(sp);

    pl.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            JPanel pnl = (JPanel) javax.swing.SwingUtilities
                    .getDeepestComponentAt((PanelsListener) e.getSource(),
                            e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (pnl != null && (!pnl.getName().equals("null.contentPane"))) {
                String name = pnl.getName();
                if (name != null) {
                    if (name.equals("First")) {
                        pl.setSize(500, 500);
                    } else if (name.equals("Second")) {
                        pl.setSize(800, 800);
                    }
                    pl.repaint();
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    pl.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

**EDIT 1**

As I understand from your comment, try instead the following:

```
public class PanelsListener extends JFrame{

public static int  panel_identifier=0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PanelsListener pl = new PanelsListener();
    pl.setSize(700, 700);
    pl.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JPanel fp=new JPanel();
    fp.setSize(200,200);
    fp.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red));
    JPanel sp=new JPanel();
    sp.setSize(200,200);
    sp.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.blue));

    pl.add(fp);
    pl.add(sp);

    //panel_identifier is used to specify which panel has been clicked.

    fp.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
           pl.panel_identifier=1;
           pl.mouseClicked(me);
        }
    });
    sp.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
            pl.panel_identifier=2;
             pl.mouseClicked(me);
        }
    });

    pl.setVisible(true);
}
protected void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
    if(panel_identifier==1)
    {
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        panel_identifier=0;
    }
    else if(panel_identifier==2)
    {
        this.setSize(800, 800);
        panel_identifier=0;
    }

}
}
```

**Normal Solution**

public class PanelsListener extends JFrame {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PanelsListener pl = new PanelsListener();
    pl.setSize(700, 700);
    pl.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    pl.add(new FirstPanel(pl));
    pl.add(new SecondPanel(pl));
    pl.setVisible(true);
}
}

class FirstPanel extends JPanel {

public FirstPanel(Frame frm) {
    setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red));
    setSize(200, 200);
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            frm.setSize(500, 500);
            frm.repaint();
        }
    });
    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            // do some action when mouse dragged over this panel
        }
    });
 }
 }

 class SecondPanel extends JPanel {

 public SecondPanel(Frame frm) {
    setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.blue));
    setSize(200, 200);
     addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
     @Override
     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
     frm.setSize(800,800);
     frm.repaint();
     }
     });

    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            // do some action when mouse dragged over this panel
        }
    });
 }
 }
```

Comment: this is using two seperate listeners. I'm trying to find a way to change a mouse motion listeners effect based on what JPanel it was clicked on.

Comment: @RoryThoman, yes and that is the proper way to solve the problem. You should NOT be attempting to use a single listener with if/else logic.

Comment: I can see what you did there, however I should have made clear I only want to use one mouse listener also, basically I have a class that extends ActionListener, MouseMotionListener, MouseListener and I am wondering if it is possible to have this one class work based on any panel I click and have a click function do something based on what panel was clicked. is there something similar to your panel_identifier solution that is a part of JPanel class? that way I can use event.getSource() then check something in there to do it.

Comment: So what the difference from just using `MouseEvent#getSource`?